# Merging column with array from multiple rows

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregation

I'm trying to merge the data from a dataset as follow:

| id | sms | longDescription | OtherFields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | contentSms | ContentDesc | xxx |
| 123 | contentSms2 | ContentDesc2 | xxx |
| 123 | contentSms3 | ContentDesc3 | xxx |
| 456 | contentSms4 | ContentDesc | xxx |

the sms and longDescription have the following structure:

```text
sms:array
|----element:struct
      |----content:string
      |----languageId:string
```

The aim is to capture the data with the same Id and merge the column `sms` and `longDescription` into one array with multiple struct( with the `languageID` as key):

| id | sms | longDescription | OtherFields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | contentSms, ContentSms2,contentSms3 | ContentDesc,ContentDesc2,ContentDesc3 | xxx |
| 456 | contentSms4 | ContentDesc | xxx |

I've tried using

```py
x = df.select("*").groupBy("id").agg( collect_list("sms"))
```

but the result is :

```text
collect_list(longDescription): array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- content: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- languageId: string (nullable = true)
```

which is an array too much, as the goal is to have an array of struct in order to have the following result:

```
sms: [{content: 'aze', languageId:'en-GB'},{content: 'rty', languageId:'fr-BE'},{content: 'poiu', languageId:'nl-BE'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`flatten`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.flatten.html) function:

```
x = df.groupBy("id").agg(flatten(collect_list("sms")))
```